# Specifying connection string in config file for a class library and re-use/modify in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, app-config, configuration-files, class-library

How can one specify the connection string in a config file of a class library and later modify this when used in a ASP.NET Web Application?

The Class library is a data access layer that has a Dataset connecting to a database based on a connection string specified in a config file (Settings.settings/app.config).

This class library is used in a web application where user inputs data and is written to the database using the DAL classes & methods exposed in the class library.

Now, I want to migrate this application from development environment to testing environment and later to production. The problem I'm facing is that after migrating to testing, the app in testing still connects to development database. I've changed the connection string mentioned in **<class library>.dll.config** file but this seems to have no impact.

Can someone explain the right way to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the .config files the name has to match the main executing assembly. For example I had a situation like yours, I needed a class library to have its settings in a .dll.config file. While it was able to reference it the actual application would not be able to read the config file because it was expecting .exe.config. Renaming the .dll.config to .exe.config fixed the problem.

In your case migrating your connection strings from .dll.config to web.config should fix your problem!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Joshua is partly right ... For posterity I would like to add a bit more to this answer as I have delt with the same problems on several occasions.  First, one must consider their architecture.  There are several issues you can run into with .config files in ASP.NET based on deployments.

Considering the architectural ramifications:

Single tier (one server):
A simple web application may be able to leverage a reference to the sites Web.config file and resolve your issues.  This would be a fine solution for a single tier application.  In the case of a windows application leveraged as a .exe file, the App.config will work too.

Multi-tier (more than one server):
Here is where things became a bit hairy for me the first time I was working with .config files across boundries.  Remember the hierarchy of the config structure and keep this in mind ([MSDN Article on .Config structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7w4sb0w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) - there is a machine.config at the root in the appropriate ASP.NET folder.  These reside at each physical server.  These are overridden by the site Web.config (or App.config) which are in turn overridden by subfolder .config files.  If you have more than one .config file you may want to use one of the methods to pass the file path for the specific .config you want to use.  More importantly, these files each may have connection information.  ASP.NET's machine.config holds some for the framework ... so you should at least be senstive to the fact this is an "inheritance" chain.  Second, any changes to the Web.config file once deployed will tell the application to restart.  This will result in loss of state (bad if you have active users on the site).  The way around this is to keep a separate .config file (e.g. connections.config) and put a reference to that file in the Web.config.  This will allow you to change the connection information (e.g. password) without having to restart the application.  Here is a link to more info: [MSDN: Working with Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This article lays out all the details you need to be aware of in a normal server / IIS deployed application.  Keep in mind that the .config files are mainly intended for applications, not libraries.  If you have several tiers, chances are you are using some communicaiton / messaging layer (e.g. WCF).  This will have / allow its own Web.config.  You can keep connection strings there (and encrypt them if needed), but better yet, put them in a second file referenced by the Web.config for manageability.  One final point, if you are ever going to consider the cloud, .config files are wrapped for application deployments which in effect removes all of the benefits they offer in terms of "not having restart or redeploy".  Azure deployments will want to consider this article to save themselves from nightmares of maintenance:  [Bill Lodin blog - Configuration files in Azul / Cloud](http://blogs.itmentors.com/bill/2009/11/04/configuration-files-and-windows-azure/).  One other point on this article – great example on how to programmatically select configuration depending on deployment!  Be sure to check that out if you want to add flexibility to deploy in or out of the cloud .

I hope these points saves all of you time and headaches.  I know I lost a couple days of programming time dealing with these issues ... and it was hard to find all the reasons in one place why may app was not "implementing" its connection object.  Hopefully this will save you all from the same fate I had.